# iOS API key From Ruby Code

Tags: ios, ruby, digital-signature, sha256, hmac

I have this code in Ruby which generates a Digital Signature based on an API KEY and some content, i have try to create some iOS code to replicate this but no success can someone help me out.

Ruby

```
key = "ZSyEULZSKlZS/SxjUbKG1cly10gyv68hvOeIYV6QLBM=".unpack('m*').to_s
hmac = HMAC::SHA256.new key
s = "some\nrandom\data\n"
hmac << s
ds_coded = [hmac.digest].pack('m*')
```

iOS

```
const char *cKey  = [@"ZSyEULZSKlZS/SxjUbKG1cly10gyv68hvOeIYV6QLBM=" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [@"some\nrandom\data\n" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey),cData , strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *hash = NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Both digital signature are always different. What can i change in my iOS code to make it the same as the Ruby code.

thanks

Comment: To get you started, ruby's default encoding is not ASCII as per your iOS code. Use `key.encoding` for a clue.

Comment: Have you taken a moment to look at the actual value of `key` in the Ruby code? `String#unpack` returns an array, and calling `to_s` on that array returns a string that looks like this, brackets and all: `["e,\x84P\xB6R*VR\xFD,cQ\xB2\x86\xD5\xC..."]`. I have a feeling that's not the string you actually want to use as your key.

Comment: Hey Jordan , yes I know how the unpack looks on Ruby, and this is what i want to use for that function , unfortunately i can't change the ruby code. "e,\204P\266R*VRý,cQ²ÕÉr×H2\277\257!\274ça^\220,\023" is the unpack.to_s from ruby . I tried to decode64 on ios to of the key and im getting something similar but without the octates  "e,P¶R*VRý,cQ²ÕÉr×H2¿¯!¼ça^," but when i use that as the key i get a nil cKey and the code breaks...

Answer (score 0):

This what at the end worked for me.

```
NSData *saltData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
NSData *paramData = [somdata dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData* hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH ];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, saltData.bytes, saltData.length, paramData.bytes, paramData.length, hash.mutableBytes);
NSString *base64Hash = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```